# How can I programmatically produce multiple copies of Crystal Reports (Details Section)?

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

I have a web page that asks the user for an input number and based on the input, an SQL query is executed and the results is then fetched to fill a Crystal Reports page. Here is the code that searches the database and fills the report: (For simplicity, I removed a lot of query string that does not add value to the question, same goes for Crystal Reports fields)

```
Dim sql As String = ""
sql = " SELECT * from table1 where input_id = '" & INPUT_NUMBER & "'"

Dim ds As DataSet = getTable(sql)
Dim orpt As New CrystalReport3
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = orpt
orpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("fldMaterialID").Text = """" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("MATERIAL_ID").ToString & """"
orpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("fldMaterialID2").Text = """" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("MATERIAL_ID").ToString & """"
orpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("fldBar").Text = """" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("MATERIAL_ID_BAR_CODE").ToString & """"
orpt.Refresh()
```

I am trying to allow the user to view multiple copies of the report. I already tried:

```
 orpt.PrintToPrinter(2, False, 0, 1)
```

But that did not work. I searched, but all the solutions I got were related to Crystal Reports with Saved Queries which is not an option for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally did it.

For those who would like to know how, or for a better `StackOverFlow.com` experience, I am glad to share the solution.

After reading [this great article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Dynamic_Crystal_Report.aspx), I was inspired by the solution and was able to accomplish the desired result by

1-Replacing the FormulaFields with an `ADO dataset` containing the same number of columns
I did that by creating a new DataSet in VS.2008 and named it `adoDataSet`. Then added all required column names to it (No linking to the actual data at this point as the data will be pulled dynamically later. This is just like a template for the data only). By default, all columns will be String typed, but that okay for my case.

3- In Crystal Reports, I used DataBase Expert to pull the mentioned dataset into the report and replaced the locations of the formula fields with the columns from the adoDataSet

4- Then in my code to populate the formulafields with data, I just called the same function that takes an SQL query and returns a normal OracleClient data set (so it might return multiple rows *as desired*)

5- This dataset however can not be used directly with Crystal Reports, so it must be first converted to the same type of the `adoDataSet` created earlier. so a simple `TryCast` did that for me.

```
Dim sql As String = ""
sql = " SELECT * from table1 where input_id = '" & INPUT_NUMBER & "'"

Dim ds As DataSet = getTable(sql)
Dim orpt As New CrystalReport3
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = orpt
dim ds1 as New adoDataSet
ds1 = TryCast(ds,adoDataSet)   ' ds is based on OracleClient data set
                        ' while adoDataSet is the one CrystalReports likes to use
orpt.SetDataSource(ds1)
```

from there I was able to generate as much copies as I wanted because I own the data, and can cause the data to appear as many times as I like.

Answer (score 0):

I've handled situations like this with these steps:

1. Create a dummy table with a field called `key` containing the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... up to some reasonable upper bound. (I use 200.)
2. Add this table in Database Expert. (You'll get a warning about multiple starting points; see below.)
3. In Select Expert, provide a formula like `{dummytable.key} <= {?numcopies}`.
4. If you're using a field value, instead of using Select Expert you can do the filtering in Database Expert at the join level.

You'll get a copy of your detail record for `key` = 1, 2, ... , `{?numcopies}`.

In my application, every record has a field called Company which all contain the same value, so I use that field to join the tables, avoiding Crystal's warning about multiple starting points. To replicate this, add a `master` key to both tables, containing the same value every record of both tables, and in Database Expert add a join on that field.

Answer (score 0):

here i am creating a crystal reports using Visual Studio 2013 and using ADO Dataset for database field on report. now i want to set default 2 copies of bill on print button on crystal report viewer. so i written code on crystal report viewer load is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
Report.Bill objRpt = new Report.Bill();
objRpt.SetDataSource(DT1);
objRpt.PrintToPrinter(2, true, 0, 0);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh(); 
}
```