# Print two copies of the same data

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I've a [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) report of one page. Only one. I want to clone that page, so when you print that report, you get two copies with the same data.

I know it can be done manually, but I want to avoid setting up the printer and write "Yes, I want two copies of this!".

```
Timelines ->

NOW ->
```

Use software, generate the Crystal Reports report, go to the in-built Crystal Reports viewer print button, write '2' in copies, print.

I WANT ->

Use software, generate Crystal Reports report, print dialog come up (this is done), you hit 'Enter' and two copies will be printed (AKA two pages which are the same)

I looked up `sub.reports`, but I don't want them in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you duplicate all the content, you can use the **New Page After Section** option to place a page break between those two copies.

If you need to avoid duplicating the content, use the hack I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467655/how-can-i-programmaticly-produce-multiple-copies-of-crystal-reports-details-sect/7520428#7520428). Just include two records in your dummy table, or to make it reusable, follow the recipe as described and use **Select Expert** to specify `{dummytable.key} <= 2`.