# Crystal Reports 10 - printing issue

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

I am using CR-10 to print a Sales order for Sage PFW.  it will print the Sales order with no problem (multi-pages if needed).
What i would like it to do is

- print that report as normal
- THEN print it again but with some of the data removed.

this will give me **a copy with pricing** and also **a copy with no pricing** for the customer to sign.  is there a way to do this automaticly when i print the report from PFW?  thank you for any help you can give me the people at SAGE had no idea if it could be done.

Rob

Comment: So, you want to hide the pricing column?  Do you also want to remove rows?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make **1 single report made my 2 sub-reports**:

- subreport with pricing
- subreport without pricing

You will see both reports on screen, and you will print both at same time.

Comment: See also my response to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704628/print-two-copies-of-the-same-data