# how to repeat group section in one page with using crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am working on school management system and i want to print fee receipt of student with crystal report tool in vb.net with visual studio 2008. my requirement is to print fee receipt two time in one page after the receipt blank page are there. i want above receipt repeat in that blank section.
please help me

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is a subreport. Place the subreport where you want the duplicate to appear, add subreport links to select which content you want displayed, and add the data sources, grouping levels, and so on.

The other solution is to provide a data source that returns two rows, like a SQL select statement or a dummy table. Join that to your data source and insert a grouping level for the field in the dummy table. I outlined it in more general terms in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520428/893113

In other words, Crystal doesn't provide a way to do this automatically.

Comment: Please mark it accepted, if you don't mind, and upvote it if you like.