# How to Repeat detail section multiple time on same page with same data in .net C#

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to repeat or copy of detail section Multiple time in same page how to do in crystal report in  C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmaticly produce multiple copies of Crystal Reports (Details Section)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467655/how-can-i-programmaticly-produce-multiple-copies-of-crystal-reports-details-sec)

Comment: is the multiple times part fixed or dynamic?